# how can I connect to my database with spring and test it?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc

I am trying to create a connection for my spring project, soemthing very simple.

I want to create the configuration fields on my application.properties. I tried with the `spring.datasource` and I dont get any error, but still, I dont get any info, just null pointers... I think the connections have not been made properly.

Here is part of my pom, with this dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.35</version>
    </dependency>
```

And my properties:

```
server.port=80
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database
jdbc.username=user
jdbc.password=password
```

I dont get any error, but when I query the database, I always get a null pointer, which makes me think is not working properly, any idea how to configure this?

Thanks

EDIT:

My configuration class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }

}
```

The controller

```
@Autowired
private MyService myService;


@RequestMapping("/")
public String index() {
    User myUser = myService.findUserById(1L);
    System.out.println(myUser);
    return myUser.getFirstName();
}
```

My Service Implementation

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;


    public User findUserById(Long id){
        return userRepository.findOne(id);
    };
}
```

My Entity

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

And my repository

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    //User findOne(Long id); this is a default method
}
```

THE ERROR:

I always get null pointer, even if data exist... and if I change the database password for a wrong one, I dont get any error.. like if it would be ok.

Comment: submit the spring xml or the spring annotation snippet

Comment: the configuration class?

Comment: How you inject the bean?

Comment: Which bean? to call the database? or the bean of configuration?

Comment: How you use the JPA bean in your application? May you provide the chain  configuration [ok provided] -> Application [ok provided] -> Service and injection of the JPA bean into the service -> method useing the JPA connector? May you post the stack trace exception?

Comment: Hi, Ive updated the post, please take a look

Comment: Why not just take an example with an embedded database or something, such as here http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-embedded-database-examples/ and then go to a database server.

Comment: I dont think this question worths a downvote...

Comment: Thanks @Snickers3192 , but this time I really need my database on a already set enviroment, I cannot change that

Comment: Obviously, but you should first have it working with a setup which you can test. If you can't get it working with apache, which should be easy, then you'll never get it working with a real database. The fact that you posted your code means that your unsure about it, so that would be an easy way to find out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Please remove below dependency from pom, because of it might let SpringBoot use h2 instead of mysql, which cause you don't see any error even with wrong mysql password.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

2) In application.properties, please use:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

These property names can be found from SpringBoot document: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html:

Answer (score 1):

The correct data source url is:

```
jdbc:mysql://HostName:Port(3306 is the default)/DBName
```

Comment: it doesnt throw an error anymore, but I still get null , even if i change the user for a wrong user, seems like i dont get other type of warning, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `@Repository` annotation on your Repository. Add that and see if that works for you.

If not,
 1. share the complete stack trace that you are getting.
2. Also, are you able to reach to the controller endpoint?

Comment: A few things to test:         
- Put a break point in your service class and see if it reaches there. Then clear and check the console that the query is actually fired. If so, what is that query?       
- Check if there is an entry in User table having id = 1.    
- In controller , if returned User object is null then you should be getting a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your entity does not implements Serializable interface.

If this is not the issue please take a look at the spring boot example from there github repository for reference.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-jpa/